# Change var to data-id value with click on button

Tags: jquery

I have this link:

```
<a class="PQReport" href="#" data-id="<?php echo $rowA['pq_id']; ?>"></a>
```

When I click that link I wan't the id of this button to change:

```
<button class="BorderBtn AskForDelete" id="">Delete</button>
```

When I click that button I wan't this script to work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.AskForDelete').click(function() {
        var id = $('.AskForDelete').attr('id');
        $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: 'delete.php',
          data: {id:id},
          dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {

            }
         });
        return false;
    });
});
```

The thing is that each link open a popup with that button (all on the same page - so no worries). Instead of making a popupbox for each link I would like to be able to just make 1 popup box that changes values depending of the link that is being clicked on.

I have tried all sorts of things - can't get it to work.

Any advice or pointers?

Thank you.

Comment: Changing id's is generally a bad idea. For example id's must be unique on a page. If you change them based on data your likely going to get the same id on different items. This will break all sorts of things and generally cause weirdness. If your storing data use `data-` attributes, if you want to activate functionality, use `class`es.

Comment: @Liam - Okay, thank you. I will look into that. Unamata's answer is working perfectly - I will modify it, so it changes the data-id instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the click on `.PQReport`. Take it's data-id and put it in `.AskForDelete`'s id. For example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.PQReport').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
    $('.AskForDelete').attr('id', $(this).data('id'))
})

    $('.AskForDelete').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $('.AskForDelete').attr('id');
         
        console.log(id);
        $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: 'delete.php',
          data: {id:id},
          dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {

            }
         });
        return false;
    });
    
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="PQReport" href="#" data-id="<?php echo $rowA['pq_id']; ?>">CLICK ME</a>


<button class="BorderBtn AskForDelete" id="">Delete</button>
```

Comment: Perfect! This works. I didn't even think about it like that. Thank you very very much!

Comment: Happy to help! Remember, always experiment! :)